# How to persist counter value when the state changes?

Tags: reactjs, state, render, assign

In this component when I change the state, it reassigns `counter=1` which I do not want. I just want that it assigns `counter=1` only once and then does not assign it again during re-render.

And, I do not want to use `useState` for `counter` to solve this issue.

```
function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(100);
    let counter = 1;
    return (
    <div>
    <button
        onClick={() => {
        setValue(value - 1);
        counter++;
        }}
    >
        click me
    </button>
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: just use useState to init counter, `const [counter, setcounter] = useState(1)`

Comment: Pass a function to `useState` instead of a value. `const [counter, setcounter] = useState(() => 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

> useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

> useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes. Mutating the
> .current property doesn’t cause a re-render.

```
function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(100)
  const counter = useRef(1)
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setValue(value - 1)
          counter.current++
        }}
      >
        click me
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can persist the counter with localStorage:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(100);
  let counter = localStorage.getItem('counter') || 1;
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setValue(value - 1);
          localStorage.setItem('counter', ++counter);
        }}
      >
        click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```